# Code:const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider) Error: window.web3 is undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs, react

I am going to connect my contract with the website.However,there was something wrong with the web3? I'm not sure.

```
import Web3 from "web3";
const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
const address = '0x9e3c32291496E8793xxxxxxxxxxxx'
const abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":.......];
const lottery = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

used the functions of contract.

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {manager:'abc'};
  }
  async componentDidMount(){
      const ManAddress = await lottery.methods.getManager().call();
      console.log('********' + ManAddress);
      this.setState({manager:ManAddress});
  }
  render() {
```

the website consoler returned

```
TypeError: window.web3 is undefined
```

Comment: if you are using web 1.* try const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://some.local-or-remote.node:8546');

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute ethereum.enable() first, see: https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/Advanced_Concepts/Provider_API

Alternatively you could disable the privacy mode of metamask (in settings / Security & Privacy) See https://medium.com/metamask/introducing-privacy-mode-42549d4870fa